# How can I git-cvsimport multiple modules from a CVS repository, with differing branches?

Tags: git, cvs, version-control, git-cvs

I'm trying to `git-cvsimport` several different modules from CVS, all of which are on different branches.

**So far I've done this (in pseudo-bash code):**

```
for each ($MODULE, $BRANCH); do
    git-cvsimport -p x -v -d "$CVS_REPO" "$MODULE" -o "$BRANCH" -C "$MODULE"
done
```

But that **makes a different git repository for each module**. How would I merge them all into one, if that's even remotely possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you could use **[git grafts](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)** to merge your repositories into one:
See ["Is there a clean way to handle two original git repositories that started with the same content?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394647/is-there-a-clean-way-to-handle-two-original-git-repositories-that-started-with-th)

In practice, you might want to look at another tool like **[cvs2git](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html)**, and check if it does not import branches in a more consistent way.

Comment: It says you need direct access to the repository to use cvs2git. If you just have remote access, it's a hack, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done is modified the git-cvsimport perl script, I've changed the `update_index()` method from:

```
sub update_index (\@\@) {
    my $old = shift;
    my $new = shift;
    open(my $fh, '|-', qw(git update-index -z --index-info))
        or die "unable to open git update-index: $!";
    print $fh
        (map { "0 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\t$_\0" }
            @$old),
        (map { '100' . sprintf('%o', $_->[0]) . " $_->[1]\t$_->[2]\0" }
            @$new)
        or die "unable to write to git update-index: $!";
    close $fh
        or die "unable to write to git update-index: $!";
    $? and die "git update-index reported error: $?";
}
```

To:

```
sub update_index (\@\@) {
    my $old = shift;
    my $new = shift;
    open(my $fh, '|-', qw(git update-index -z --index-info))
        or die "unable to open git update-index: $!";
    print $fh
        (map { "0 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\t$cvs_tree/$_\0" }
            @$old),
        (map { '100' . sprintf('%o', $_->[0]) . " $_->[1]\t$cvs_tree/$_->[2]\0" }
            @$new)
        or die "unable to write to git update-index: $!";
    close $fh
        or die "unable to write to git update-index: $!";
    $? and die "git update-index reported error: $?";
}
```

(Notice the addition of the `$cvs_tree` variable.)

Works like a charm. To execute:

```
perl git-cvsimport -v ... (rest of regular git-cvsimport arguments)
```

Comment: just tried with 1.7.5 on centos 5.5 and it failed. tried perl /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-cvsimport -v   -d /root/cvs_mirror/java -C testdir -r cvs -k

Comment: forget it, I got it: one needs to add the full path to the repo as the module name - it wasn't clear from your description: the correct command line is git cvsimport -v   -d /path/to/repo -C testdir -r cvs -k /path/to/repo