# Merging changes from CVS repository to a GIT repository

Tags: git, merge, cvs

Currently my team of 5 is using a GIT repository to track changes we make in our module and some in other shared modules. But we have a CVS repository which is being used by all other teams to maintain other modules. So CVS repository has latest changes of all modules.

Now my doubt is how can I take changes from CVS repository to GIT repository .. is there any simplified or a FOOL PROOF way to merge these changes from CVS to git.

Actually our code in GIT was taken from CVS few months back and now we want to update it with changes from CVS with the latest features and changes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is here : [How can I git-cvsimport multiple modules from a CVS repository, with differing branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203510/how-can-i-git-cvsimport-multiple-modules-from-a-cvs-repository-with-differing-b?rq=1)

Doesn't `git cvsimport` works?

Comment: But I just need to merge only the changes which are done in CVS from initial checkout to current checkout. cvsimport will create a new git repository for it but I need to merge all the changes into my current git repository

Comment: Well, I keep reading `git cvsimport` is used for **incremental** imports, what does that mean if not "getting what you don't already have"? Additionnaly, you should have look at the man page ( `git help cvsimport` or http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cvsimport.html )

Comment: I am not really great with CVS or GIT .. Can you help me out with the command for cvsimport where I can import changes from CVS to git .. since git is maintained by me I knew the repo. But in case of cvs i just use cvs co -r release1 command to checkout the code

Comment: Hum, I think I pasted the wrong link in my first post, here is what i meant : http://stackoverflow.com/a/586225/325369 I think it explains precisely what you want.